# How to run a shell script .sh file in java

Tags: java, linux, wso2, sh, wso2-esb

**Objective**

I wrote a simple java program where I want to rename a file and then simply I want to run my **permission.sh** file.

**Problem Statement**

What is happening that my file name is getting change successfully but permission.sh file is not being executed. Stuck need help!

Following is my code.

```
package nl.ggmd.file.Permission;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext;
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;

public class FilePermission extends AbstractMediator
{

  public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
      try {
      File oldfile =new File("/ggmd/files/uploads/FIle contract1.csv");
        File newfile =new File("/ggmd/files/uploads/contract1.csv");

        if(oldfile.renameTo(newfile)){
            System.out.println("Rename succesful");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Rename failed");
        }


          Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/opt/file/contracts/tst/permissions.sh"); 
          BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                  proc.getInputStream()));
          try {
              proc.waitFor();
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          }
          while (read.ready()) {
              System.out.println(read.readLine());
          }
      } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }


    return true;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

This java code is s custom class mediator of WSO2 ESB and wso2 does not show logs of java mediator is its not possible for me to debug the issue.

Following is my permission.sh code.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /ggmd/files/uploads/
file=contract1.csv

if [ ! -a $file ]
then
  sudo chmod 664 $file && echo "The file is now writable"
else
  echo "The file is already writable"
fi
```

Comment: does the sh script has executable permission?

Comment: where is permissions.sh ?? Add the snippet as well for that. Also make sure that the executable permission is enabled for groups or other if the user executing the same isn't the owner of the file

Comment: what is the error message please? (permission, or file not found?) or does the script failed in the middle for some reason like: you are not running it from the proper working directory?

Comment: @Scary Wombat  Yes permssions.sh han all the permissions

Comment: @Allan I have edited my question

Comment: Why do people vote down to question without actually telling the problem. This is not ok.

Comment: To address your original problem - you can actually debug custom mediators in wso2 esb with java remote debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is much advisable to use the [Process Builder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). It is really built for this kind of tasks.

Your program `permisions.sh` is not an executable as Java understands it, even though the operating system understands it as an executable file.

You need to inform Java that the bash shell (or some other shell) is needed to execute your command. eg. /bin/bash is the path to the program that can run or execute your script. With that said you follow this code snippet bellow to fix get that working.

```
public class FilePermission extends AbstractMediator
{

  public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
      try {
      File oldfile =new File("/ggmd/files/uploads/FIle contract1.csv");
        File newfile =new File("/ggmd/files/uploads/contract1.csv");

        if(oldfile.renameTo(newfile)){
            System.out.println("Rename succesful");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Rename failed");
        }

private final String commandPath = "/bin/bash";

private final String scriptPath = "/opt/file/contracts/tst/permissions.sh";


try {
        Process execCommand = new ProcessBuilder(commandPath, scriptPath).start();
        execCommand.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exceptions
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


    return true;
  }
}
```

Please note that the above code may need some modification especially if your script(permissions.sh) may depend on the current working directory. with the above the working directory of the java code is being used.

but can be changed by calling the `directory(File directory)` method on the process object. then pass the new working directory path to it. In this case

```
Process execCommand = new ProcessBuilder(commandPath, scriptPath).directory(new File("/some/directory/to/be/used/")).start();
```

You can also call the `execCommand.getErrorStream();` or `execCommand.getInputStream();` where needed.

Comment: I am in /ggmd/files/uploads over there i am renaming file and also I want to run permission.sh in same directory.

Comment: I am running this in java code in wso2 and wso2 esb does not show programs error. File name is changed but not executing permissions.sh

Comment: I tried first method not this one directory(File directory) beacuse I am in same directory

Comment: ok my best guess is when you manually run the code it requests for a password...which you can enter especially for this line. try removing the sudo and from that command and see if it works

sudo chmod 664 $file && echo "The file is now writable"

Comment: Well when I manually run the code it does not ask for password

Comment: This is most likely because you are running as root manually so it will not ask for password.
but I am sure java will run it as a different user therefore sudo will request for a password but since executing the script is not interactive there will be no provision for entering the password. therefore it will not execute the whole script.

Comment: You are right manually I run permissions file with appliance user which is a root user. I keep file in a directory with "file uploader" user and then wso2 picks that file then I want java to change file name and run that script. File uploader user do not have access to shell.

Comment: What can I do now?

Comment: Thanks bro I found and alternate way to manage it on linux side. Thanks. yes you were right problem was with password and root user.

Comment: Great glad I could help